# How to Lookup First column that is not empty and Return Corresponding Column Header In an Excel block of cells

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula, is-empty

I am trying to Lookup First column that is not empty and Return Corresponding Column Header In an Excel block of cells (I think called Array?)

For example:

[In this picture, I want to look at all of the entries in B4:G9, and have my formula tell me the first column not to be empty is the column labeled as 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J99nO.png)

I have the following formula so far that seems to work, where I search each row, have each row return the column header that the first non-zero number shows up in, and then search the minimum of the returned column headers. However my actual data has more than 100 columns and 100 lines, so I am looking for something cleaner.

```
=MIN(
INDEX($B$3:$G$3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B9:G9<>0),0),0)),
INDEX($B$3:$G$3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B8:G8<>0),0),0)),
INDEX($B$3:$G$3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B7:G7<>0),0),0)),
INDEX($B$3:$G$3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B6:G6<>0),0),0)),
INDEX($B$3:$G$3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B5:G5<>0),0),0)),
INDEX($B$3:$G$3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B4:G4<>0),0),0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

This formula should work for you, adjust the `$B$4:$G$9` to match your actual dataset:

```
=INDEX($3:$3,1,MIN(IF($B$4:$G$9<>0,COLUMN($B$4:$G$9),COLUMNS($3:$3))))
```

***Note:*** Depending on your version of Excel, you may have to confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  That will force the formula to be calculated as an array.  You'll know you've done it correctly when the formula is surrounded by curly braces `{formula}` (the braces aren't put in manually, they're put in automatically upon successful array entry via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: I am still a bit new to excel, can you explain a bit what the formula you provided is doing? that way I can try to adjust it to my actual data.

Also when I put it against the example data (in the picture) it gives me back a 2, not a 1. Any ideas? Maybe I referenced something wrong?

Comment: After playing with it, it seems to always give the column after the one I want

Comment: The formula is checking for non-zero cells, and returning their column number.  It then gets the minimum column number (which would be a 2 for column B), and then feeds it to the outer INDEX to get the appropriate header from row 3 (which is why it should just be `$3:$3` and not `$B$3:$G$3`) so that it returns the correct header.  The only range adjustment should be the data body range of `$B$4:$G$9` to suit your data.